Trying to use Python & Selenium to click on a slider/checkbox
I'm trying to use python & Selenium to click on a slider/checkbox on a website and I'm having a lot of difficulty. I can simply find the element by ID (1369) and click on it no worries, except the ID numbers change dynamically over time so they are proving pretty much useless to me.
I also tried finding the element by class, XPath, etc. and clicking on it using many questions posted to Stack Overflow as reference with no luck, as there seems to be some differences in the HTML code in my scenario that are stopping me from progressing. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!
Reference HTML as text:


<div class="f-box vcbox">
  <span class="text-item box-item">Single date</span>
  <div id="1369" class="checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary  ">
    <label>
      <em class="fake-input  "></em>
      <span>
        ::before
      </span>
    </label>
</div>



Reference HTML code on website
Code that works when the ID is known in advance:
driver.find_element(By.ID, "1369").click()

Code that hasn't worked:
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'em.checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary').click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary').click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(.,'Single date')]").click()


I also tried finding the element by class/xpath This should work, with the right xpath expression.  Show us what you tried.

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted. In addition, a link to the page would be really helpful in cases like this.

@ me after you've updated your question with the HTML as text. I have an answer but I want to test it first.

Hi all. Thanks for your input. I've updated my post to include what you've asked for. If there's anything that can be improved from my end please let me know and I'll be happy to edit again as required.

@JeffC happy to try out any suggestions thank you but the website requires a logon that I can’t give out for others to try testing sorry mate.

@Benny88 That's why I request relevant HTML as text. I have a dummy HTML file on my desktop that I can paste your HTML into, open that page in the browser, and then test locators. While many times a URL is better because timing and other issues, this is at least a decent substitute.

@JeffC makes perfect sense. If I post any more questions in the future I'll be sure to structure them in this way.

Given the HTML
<span class="text-item box-item">Single date</span>
<div id="1369" class="checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary  ">

We have an element nearby that can be uniquely identified using contained text,
<span class="text-item box-item">Single date</span>

using and XPath
(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Single date']")

From there, we can find the DIV right below it using following-sibling,
(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Single date']/following-sibling::div[1]")

